# how to exclude comma in my regular expression

Tags: regex

my character set is

```
-68,-79,-72,-70,-71,-71,-71,-71,-72,-73,R2,0000feaa-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
```

I want like

-68 -79        -73

and my regular expression is

```
[-][0-9]{2}[^0-9]
```

and result like

```
-68, -79,
```

I want to exclude comma in my character set

how can I solve my problem

Thank you for your help

Comment: have you tried replacing all the commas by a space?

Comment: thank you.solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

Based on your regex and your results, I assume you are finding multiple matches and then putting spaces between each match.  Let me break down what your regex is doing:

1. `[-]` matches the negative sign
2. `[0-9]{2}` matches two digits
3. `[^0-9]` matches any non-digit character, including a comma.  So the commas are **part of your match**

If you want to exclude the commas from your match, but still assert that they are there, you need to use a positive lookahead.  This is done like so:

```
[-][0-9]{2}(?=[^0-9])
```

Answer (score 0):

Already said this in the comments but will post answer just for the sake of completion.

The solution to this isn't exactly regex. It's the `replace` function of whatever tool you're using. All you have to do is replace the `,` by a   (space).

For example, in python `.replace(',', ' ')` is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

which language are you using?

For example:

sed

```
echo "-34,-35,-34" | sed 's/,/ /g'
```

awk

```
echo "-34,-35,-34" | awk '{gsub(/,/, " ", $0); print $0}'
```